# Spatial file manager for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

For a variety of reasons, I’m switching from Linux to Windows as my primary operating system. I’ve never used Windows at home, and very rarely at school, so I don’t know much about the software choices available. There are a lot of guides for people doing the switch in the opposite direction, but nothing for me.

I really like the “spatial mode” provided by the Nautilus file manager for Linuces — that's when a file manager opens a new window for every folder, does not open a new window for folders that are already open, and remembers all view settings for every folder. Like old Macs did (an eloquent defence of this approach can be found [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2003/04/finder.ars)). Is there anything similar for Windows 7? It seems like most of my workflows depend on it, and this is a constant source of frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable this functionality in the standard windows explorer browser.

Open up a file window then press the ALT key to make the menu appear.

Select *Tools* then *Folder Options*

Turn on *Open each folder in its own window*

Each folder already remembers its own view setting.

Comment: Thank you! this makes it more tolerable. Can I also get rid of the sidebar, the huge “details” strip in the bottom of the window, and the toolbars? Those options are not in _Folder Options_, and I’m going to have many windows, so real estate is important.

Comment: Click on the organise button in the top left then under layout untick Details Pane and Navigation Pane :)

Comment: How to remove the useless navigation/address bar then?